# Mac: Opening large files creates `invalid argument` error

Tags: python, macos, conda, miniconda, sumatra

I am currently trying to open a large file on my 64 bit Mac (using 64 bit Miniconda, as this is the only version for [mac](https://conda.io/miniconda.html)). I use a framework 'sumatra' which is a library to track scientific computing work and possibly reproduce it. I get the following error. I was able to debug a little, and found out that it is mainly due to X_train.npy being too big (3.6GB when not unpacked).

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/davidal/miniconda3/envs/ml_project/bin/smt", line 31, in <module>
    main(sys.argv[2:])
  File "/Users/davidal/miniconda3/envs/ml_project/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sumatra/commands.py", line 372, in run
    project.allow_command_line_parameters)
  File "/Users/davidal/miniconda3/envs/ml_project/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sumatra/commands.py", line 76, in parse_arguments
    parameters = build_parameters(arg)
  File "/Users/davidal/miniconda3/envs/ml_project/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sumatra/parameters.py", line 586, in build_parameters
    parameters = parameter_set_class(filename)
  File "/Users/davidal/miniconda3/envs/ml_project/lib/python3.5/site-packages/parameters/__init__.py", line 387, in __init__
    pstr = f.read()
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

Any experience resolving such issues? Where should I look further? Any ideas?

Comment: I doubt that file size is the issue. Please post code and other relevant info.

Comment: Having the same issue. Worked for small files, but now having issues for big ones.